# Angular 2/ASP.NET Core-retrieving id from url

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, angular2-routing, url-parameters

I want to retrive a id from a specific product thru the url. This is my code so far:

**Imports**

```
//Imports from @Angular
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router, Params, RouterLink, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

**constructor**

```
 constructor(
        private _hatListService: HatListService, private _router: Router, private _params: ActivatedRoute) {

    }
```

**hat-editor.component ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit() {

           this._params.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        var id = params['id'] * 1;//*1 efter det som man vill parse:s so bilr det som int.parse

        this._hatListService.getHat(this.id).subscribe(

            foundHats => this.thisHatModel = foundHats);
        console.log(this.thisHatModel)
    });

}
```

**service**

```
public _getHatById: string = '/api/Hats/GetHatById';

      getHat(id: number): Observable<Hat> {
            //debugger
            return this._http.get(this._getHatById + '/' + id).map(res => <Hat>res.json()).catch(this.handleError);


        }
```

**controller**

> ```
>     // GET: api/Hats/5
>     [HttpGet("GetHatById/{id}")]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> GetHat([FromRoute] int id)
>     {
>         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             return BadRequest(ModelState);
>         }
>
>         var hat = await _context.Hat.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
>
>         if (hat == null)
>         {
>             return NotFound();
>         }
>
>         return Ok(hat);
>     }
> ```

When I hover over each product the url is produced:

[image]

But when I click the product the id is not caught from the browser:

[image]

contoller:

[image]

I am guessing the error occurs on this line in my getHat() method. The *1 is for casting the id to a number:

> ```
> >      this._params.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
>             var id = params['id'] * 1;
>
>         });
> ```

I tried the Angualr.io exapmlpe but could not get it to work for me. **Thanx for all the help**

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it** changed this:

> var id = params['id'] * 1;

to:

> public id: any;
>
> this.id = params['id'] * 1;

and it worked.